# in R, what is difference between kmeans() and kmeansCBI()?

Tags: r, k-means

I tried both `kmeans()` and `kmeansCBI()` from the `fps` package on my dataset.

But, they give different [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) value, so I don't know which one is correct value.

For example, with 700*5 data, `kmeans()` gives me approximately 33000 as SSE, but `kmeansCBI()` gives me 120 as SSE.

What value should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: did you set.seed before each of these procedures? kmeans depends on a set seed for reproducible results.

Answer (score 3):

From the package descriptions:
`kmeans()` uses Hartigan and Wong equation while `kmeansCBI()` is an interface to the function of `kmeansruns()` and calls `kmeans()`.

You can read the help for any function by using `?` in front of the function name.  I am not sure why you are getting different answers but I would advise you to check out the documentation to make sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: You could also set.seed() for reproducible examples!